# Dynamically create virtual directory

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm working on an application, where I need to create a temporary link on page load. Essentially, I will create a virtual directory in IIS using command line on page load, and delete the virtual directory afterwards. My question, will I run into any performance issues with IIS constantly manipulating virtual directories?

Comment: its better to use a handler to send the files, a database to keep the "directory name" and a programmatically way to re-write the url and served by the handler

Comment: To implement this functionality you will need to run process under user who has IIS admin privileges which may create security hole. Hence may not be good idea.

Comment: I am using a handler for certain functions, but this particular page needs access to a static file, I can't use filestreamresult. Can URL Rewrite module be changed dynamically?